# issue regarding postgres function test run in jmeter

Tags: java, postgresql, testing, jdbc, jmeter

**i am testing a plpgsql function in jmeter**.
The following sample is to replicate the issue. i have a table named sing with definition as follows

db=# \d sing

Table "schema1.sing"

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| id | bigint |
| valr | numeric |

and my plpgsql function is as follows

```
create or replace function schema1.insissue(val text) returns text as $$
declare
  _p text;_h text;
  ids text[];
  valid numeric := functiontochangetoid(val); // a sample function to change value into id.
  slid bigint:= nextval('rep_s'); // sequence value
  dup text := null;
begin
 select array_agg(id) from sing where valr = valid into ids;
 raise notice 'ids %',ids;
 if coalesce(array_upper(ids,1),0) > 0 then
   dup = 'FAIL';
 end if;
 raise notice 'dup %',dup;
 if dup is null then
  insert into sing values (slid,valid);
  return 'SUCCESS'|| slid;
 end if;
  return 'FAIL';
exception
  when others then
  get stacked diagnostics
  _p := pg_exception_context,_h := pg_exception_hint;
  raise notice 'sqlerrm >> :%',sqlerrm;
  raise notice 'position >> :%',_p;
  raise notice 'hint >> :%',_h;
  return 'FAIL';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

simply in my function it checks if the value exist in valr column of sing table and if not exist inserts the value to the table.

now my jmeter config
[image: connection config]

[image: userthread]

[image: sampler]

to connect i use postgresql-42.2.14.jar.
when the ramp up period is 1 sec IE 200 request in one second the function creates duplicate values like this, when ramp up period is 100 sec no issue.

db=# select * from sing;

| id | valr |
| --- | --- |
| 897 | 1095 |
| 898 | 1095 |
| 89+ | 1095 |
| 900 | 1095 |
| 901 | 1095 |
| 902 | 1095 |
| 903 | 1095 |

but it shoul be actually like this

db=# select * from sing;

| id | valr |
| --- | --- |
| 897 | 1095 |

how can i avoid these type of duplicate values ?  because my  app will have high traffic may be  100 calls in second also i can't make "valr" column a primary key. because it contains other type of values.

my postgres version

```
    db=# select version();
                                                     version                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.3 (Debian 12.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

Comment: I already tried  check constraint, trigger,rules etc. but still i can't implement any  successful logic..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at last found the solution , the transaction isolation to serialize works for my actual problem. checkout this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-set-transaction.html. The transaction is read committed by default. when we change transaction to serialization on a session it works.
To make a transaction serialized you can use set command on a session before any select query

```
 SET transaction isolation level serializable;
```

it cannot be done inside a function or procedure in PostgreSQL only for sessions. we can use set in procedure but there will an error like this

```
NOTICE:  sqlerrm >> :SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query
NOTICE:  position >> :SQL statement "SET transaction isolation level serializable"
```